# add the word "somme" in the end of the table

Tags: vb.net, excel

this is my code:

```
     xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Sheets(ComboBox1.Text), Excel.Worksheet)
    xlWorkSheet.Activate()
    xlApp.Visible = True


    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim lastcol As Integer


    With xlWorkSheet
        .Select()
        j = xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Column
        lastrow=xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Rows.End(XlDirection.xlDown).Row                                              
         lastcol = xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Columns.End(XlDirection.xlToRight).Column
        For thiscol = j To lastcol
            .Cells(lastrow + 1, thiscol).Value = _
            xlApp.Sum(.Range(.Cells(1, thiscol), .Cells(lastrow, thiscol)))
        Next
    End With
```

i want to add the word "sum" in the end of the table 
when i find the end of the table i insert the word "sum"

Comment: What do you consider the end of your table? Like each cell in the last column should have the word "Sum" or each cell in the row should have the word "Sum"?

Comment: i want it in the end of the first colone of the table

Answer (score 0):

After `next', and before`End With` add a line like:

```
.cells(lastRow + 2, 1).value = "Somme"
```

That will put the word "Somme" after the last row of data in the first column.

Comment: when i calculate the sum of my table, after the word i have 0 can you tell me how i delete it

Comment: i want to write the world somme into the cell
when i have 0 in the end of the table

Comment: I hate to ask, but would you mind posting a picture of what you mean. I'm really having a hard time figuring exactly what you are you looking for. Perhaps if I had a picture of what your table looks like and what you want when the subroutine runs, I could figure it out.

Comment: titre 
             BSC Name    Site Name            Cell Name     TCH Traffic (Erl)
             BSFXE1         BOURGUIBA02    26CK2GA      9,36
             BSFXE2         AJENGA               44AJEGC      19,47
             BSFXE1         BOURGUIBA02    26BG1GA      4,43
             Somme          0                           0                   33.26
    i want to delete these 0

Comment: the is the result :
somme |  0  | 0  |  33.26
i want to delete the 0

Comment: I think my code was pretty close above, I was just off by a Row. I just editted it. It should put "Somme" at the last row of the first column, just beneath your Summed' values.

Comment: how can i add a picture to see my table